# Gtk# destroy event

Tags: mono, gtk, gtk#

In Gtk#, I can hook up a handler for the "destroy" event but it never gets called.  This application never prints anything out.  The Gtk docs say that the "destroy" event is only sent if a certain flag is set, and also says that this flag is automatically set by Gdk.

This is frustrating, since it's basically identical to plain Gtk+ code that works correctly.  And how do I know when to call `Application.Quit()` except by listening to the "destroy" event?

```
using System;
using Gtk;

public class MainWindow {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application.Init();
        Window win = new Window("Test");
        win.Resize(200, 200);
        win.DestroyEvent += new DestroyEventHandler(OnDestroy);
        win.ShowAll();
        Application.Run();
    }

    private static void OnDestroy(object o, DestroyEventArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnDestroy");
    }
}
```

P.S. I'm not interested in the "delete" event.

Comment: Why are you not interested in the delete event?

Comment: @ptomato: Gtk docs: "delete-event signal is emitted if a user requests that a toplevel window is closed" -- I want to know when the window is closed, not when the user requests it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The gtk-sharp wrapper installs its own destroy event handler that gets invoked first and disconnects your handler. However in turn it provides a `Destroyed` event. You can use that, as follows:

```
using System;
using Gtk;

public class MainWindow {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application.Init();
        Window win = new Window("Test");
        win.Resize(200, 200);
        win.Destroyed += new EventHandler(OnDestroy);
        win.ShowAll();
        Application.Run();
    }

    private static void OnDestroy(object o, EventArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnDestroy");
        Application.Quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, this works, but now the question is where it is documented.  I see no "Destroyed" event in the docs: http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=T%3aGtk.Widget%2fE

Comment: Documented? It's open source! LOL. Seriously, it took me some digging in the source code to find why your code didn't work. Documentation should indeed point this out, although it [does have](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=E%3aGtk.Object.Destroyed) the `Destroyed` event (it's inherited from `Gtk.Object`).