# Trouble trying to create a DatePicker in GTK#

Tags: c#, mono, gtk#

I'm new to GTK# (and desktop development for that matter) and I can't figure out what seems like to be a simple task. :(

I can't get a simple date picker to work. I have a main window with a single text box entry and a single button. When the button is clicked it opens a new window with the calendar widget and when the user double-clicks a date it then should return the selected date to the text box entry on the main window.

Here is my code, what am I missing?

MainWindow.cs

```
using System;
using Gtk;

public partial class MainWindow: Gtk.Window
{   
    public MainWindow (): base (Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel)
    {
        Build ();
    }

    protected void OnDeleteEvent (object sender, DeleteEventArgs a)
    {
        Application.Quit ();
        a.RetVal = true;
    }

    private DateTest1.CalendarTest datePicker;

    protected void OnButton1Clicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        datePicker = new DateTest1.CalendarTest();
        datePicker.DestroyEvent += new DestroyEventHandler(datePickerDestroyed); 
        datePicker.ShowAll(); 
    }

    public void datePickerDestroyed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        entry1.Text = datePicker.DatePicked.ToString();
    } 
}
```

CalendarTest.cs

```
using System;

namespace DateTest1
{
    public partial class CalendarTest : Gtk.Window
    {
        public DateTime DatePicked;

        public CalendarTest () : 
                base(Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel)
        {
            this.Build ();
        }

        protected void OnCalendar1DaySelectedDoubleClick (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var datePicker = (Gtk.Calendar)sender;
            DatePicked = datePicker.Date;
            this.Destroy();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code seems fine. Try running it in MD's debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `Destroyed` event, not the `DestroyEvent` ;)
That is, use this:
`datePicker.Destroyed += new EventHandler(datePickerDestroyed);`

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13171222/gtk-destroy-event/13211127).